# Webpage fails when stripe $charge (create array) is run, without it, the web page appears

Tags: php, html, stripe-payments

I am stuck at the checkout stage on my website. When I click on pay, it should take a stripe charge, update the database tables and view a thank you message. This was working until yesterday morning. I have reverted my code back to before then and it still isn't working.

I have narrowed the issue down to the following within my order_confirmation.php page. Without the $charge section, the webpage loads fine. 
the $charge section: This is within a try/catch.

```
  $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
       "amount"        =>  $charge_amount,
       "currency"      =>  CURRENCY,
       "description"   =>  $description,
       "source"        =>  $token,
       "receipt_email" =>  $email,
       "metadata"      =>  $metadata)
 );
```

The actual results should be the $charge details will be updated at Stripe (payment gateway), the database is updated and the cart cookie is destroyed.

It seems like the update to Stripe isn't working (because the code won't run with the $charge array), the database doesn't get updated (as I believe this is done once the cookie is expired).

It's odd how it was working fine, I have checked and when I coded the $charge array a few months back the standard was to like I have added in the code section. But Stripe says remove array() and add []. I have tried this and it still doesn't work.

I have tried to google this, and it looks like I have entered the code correctly. I have used Google Chrome DOM to investigate, but it seems when I add $charge array in the code all I get loaded on the webpage is up to my navigation bar, nothing more. 
If any of you can give me some help that would be greatly appreciated.

the try/catch block of code is this:

```
try {
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  "amount"        =>  $charge_amount,
  "currency"      =>  CURRENCY,
  "description"   =>  $description,
  "source"        =>  $token,
  "receipt_email" =>  $email,
  "metadata"      =>  $metadata)
);

// adjust inventory
$itemQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
$iresults = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemQ);
$items = json_decode($iresults['items'],true);

$newSizes = array();
foreach($items as $item){

$item_id = $item['id'];
$productQ = $db->query("SELECT sizes FROM products WHERE id = 
'{$item_id}'");
 $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQ);
 $sizes = sizesToArray($product['sizes']);

 $sizes[$item['size']] -= $item['quantity']; // we deduce the relevant q-ty
$sizesString = sizesToString($sizes);
$db->query("UPDATE products SET sizes = '{$sizesString}' WHERE id = 
'{$item_id}'");
}

// Update cart
$db->query("UPDATE cart SET paid = 1, uid = '{$user_id}'  WHERE id = 
'{$cart_id}'");
$db->query("INSERT into transactions
  (user_id,charge_id,cart_id,first_name,last_name,email,billing_address, 
billing_town, billing_postcode, delivery_address, delivery_town, delivery_postcode,sub_total,tax,grand_total,description,txn_type) VALUES 
  ('$user_id', '$charge->id','$cart_id', '$first_name','$last_name','$email','$billing_address','$billing_town','$billing_postcode', '$delivery_address','$delivery_town','$delivery_postcode','$sub_total','$tax','$grand_total','$description','$charge->object')");  
  mail('EMAIL', 'Order Confirmation: ALPHA ' 
.$cart_id, $message, 'From: EMAIL');

    $domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')? 
 '.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:true; //destroying cart cookie
 setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,"/",$domain,false);

$product_id = $item['id'];
$productQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = 
'{$product_id}'");
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQ);

if($cart_id != ''){
 $cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
$items = json_decode($result['items'],true);
$i = 1;
$sub_total = 0;
$delivery = 0;
$item_count = 0;
 }
 ?>

 <head>
 <title>Order Confirmation | BUSINESS NAME</title>
 </head>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
     <div class="col-12" id="ordconf">
       <i class="far fa-calendar-check"></i>
       <medium>Thank you for your order</medium><br>
       <medium>Your Order # is: <strong>ALPHA<?=$cart_id;?></strong> 
       </medium><br>
       <small>We will review your order, and get back to you shortly with 
    confirmation that your order has been accepted.<br>
        if you have any queries about your order, please go to - Support: 
 <a href="contactus.php" class="bluetxt">here</a>
    </small>
    <br>
    <small>By placing an order with us, you are agreeing to all our policies.<br>
      <a href="terms&conditions.php" class="bluetxt">Terms</a>&nbsp;
      <a href="privacy&cookiepolicy.php" class="bluetxt">Privacy</a>&nbsp;
      <a href="refundpolicy.php" class="bluetxt">Refund</a>&nbsp;
      <a href="returnspolicy.php" class="bluetxt">Returns</a>
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php

include 'includes/footer2.php';

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
// Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
$body = $e->getJsonBody();
 $err  = $body['error'];

print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
// param is '' in this case
print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
} catch (\Stripe\Error\RateLimit $e) {
// Too many requests made to the API too quickly
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
// Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
// Authentication with Stripe's API failed
// (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
// Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
// Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
// yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
// Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your script dies at some point. Enable full PHP error reporting, and see if you get any messages.

Comment: Would that be via the browser or without my code editor?

Comment: You are only catching an exception of one very specific type here - so if this throws any other type of exception, you don’t catch it at all. Catch all exceptions, regardless of type, and see what you get then.

Comment: Ok I’ll add them in and try again.

Comment: I have added in stripes errors exceptions and it still shows blank. I have edited my post to include the stripe exceptions

Comment: Well then start by enabling proper PHP error reporting. Research what that means, if unclear.